# In windows, where to create the `.theanorc.txt` file and how to make theano able to see it?

Tags: windows, theano

I am trying to make thenao use gpu on windows. [This](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html) tutorial suggests that I create a `.theanorc` directory at my `home` and a `theanorc.txt` inside it to be able to set the configuration flags before initialization.

Where to create the `theanorc.txt` file (i.e. how to find out where my home is?) and how to make theano able to see it?
I have tried the following script to create `.theanorc` and then added `theanorc.txt` manually inside it, but `gpu` was not enabled:

```
import os
_theano_base_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
if not os.access(_theano_base_dir, os.W_OK):
    _theano_base_dir = '/tmp'

_theano_dir = os.path.join(_theano_base_dir, '.theanorc')
if not os.path.exists(_theano_dir):
    os.makedirs(_theano_dir)

theano_config_path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(_theano_dir, 'theanorc.txt'))
print (theano_config_path)
```

This printed: `C:\SPB_Data\.theanorc\theanorc.txt` Is `C:\SPB_Data` my `home`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, your home directory should be `C:\Users\Your_Windows_UserName`. Also if you want to create the `.theanorc` file without the `.txt` extension you can use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)